# How do you install free IBM WebSphere Application Server for Developers

Tags: java, websphere, websphere-liberty

I have downloaded and unzipped in a directory to get disc1 to disc3 folders but there's no exe to launch and no instruction in readme file so how do you install ?

IBM WebSphere Application Server for Developers, including Liberty Profile v8.5 (Part 1 of 3)
was.repo.8500.developers.ilan_part1.zip  (988M)

Download now

IBM WebSphere Application Server for Developers, including Liberty Profile v8.5 (Part 2 of 3)
was.repo.8500.developers.ilan_part2.zip  (1G)

Download now

IBM WebSphere Application Server for Developers, including Liberty Profile v8.5 (Part 3 of 3)
was.repo.8500.developers.ilan_part3.zip  (910M)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need IBM Installation Manager to install that. The disks you downloaded are simply the repositories of the software that IIM can read and process.

For example, the 1.5 version can be found [here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg24032358).

Comment: Thanks but what a hassle when you have a lot of other stuffs to do :(

Comment: It is really bad idea to have a lot of thing to download. Very confused by this. :(

Answer (score 2):

If you do not want to download compressed archives containing the Installation Manager repositories, then there is a much easier and simpler process for getting WebSphere Application Server for Developers installed.

Once you have IBM Installation Manager installed, you only need to provide the repository location to where the IBM hosted WebSphere Application Server for Developers repository is located.  For instance, to install WAS for Developers version 8.0 or version 8.5, you simply add one of the following repository locations to the repository preferences.

- V8.0: http://www.ibm.com/software/repositorymanager/V8WASDeveloperILAN
- V8.5: http://www.ibm.com/software/repositorymanager/V85WASDeveloperILAN

Information on [installing WAS for Developers using IBM hosted repositories](https://developer.ibm.com/wasdev/downloads/#asset/WAS_traditional_for_Developers) in available on WASDev.net.

Alternatively, you can use the IBM Package Utility (a companion to Installation Manager), to reconstruct the IBM hosted repository on your local machine. The advantage to using PU is that you will be able to create a local repository that also includes the fixpack level of your own choosing rather than having to go get a fixpack from IBM Fix Central and then updating the installation afterwards.

Information on [creating local repositories with Packaging Utility](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.installation.nd.doc/ae/tins_creating_cust_reps.html) is available in the WebSphere Knowledge Center.

Comment: am getting Error 404: java.io.FileNotFoundException: SRVE0190E: File not found: /V8WASDeveloperILAN

Answer (score 0):

You have to download IBM Installation Manager and install it. Then run the Installation Manager by click on `Restart Installation Manager`. After all press `Install` and in the new page press 'Repositories'. In the `Repositories` locate the directory you extracted IBM WebSphere Application Server then select `repository.conf` and stick with defaults to continue installation.

Download or run Eclipse and go to `Help > Eclipse Marketplace` and search for `IBM WebSphere` and press install to add IBM WebSphere into your Eclipse Environment.

To install new version you can follow the below link with complete guidance.
https://developer.ibm.com/wasdev/downloads/#asset/WAS_traditional_for_Developers

Answer (score 0):

A solution is to install the official docker image:

https://hub.docker.com/r/ibmcom/websphere-traditional/

there are all the versions from 8.5.5.9 to the newest, BASE and ILAN licenses.